# toggling button should redirect to package accessibility

Tags: android, android-layout, permissions, accessibility

**I just want to redirect from the first screen to the second screen when the user clicks on the toggle button.**

MainActivity.java

```
private static final int CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION = 2084;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            //If the draw over permission is not available open the settings screen
            //to grant the permission.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
//            Use the below code to navigate the settings of accessibility directly when user cl
//            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
//            startActivityForResult(intent,CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            initializeView();
        }


    }
```

I have implemented OnpressBack
@Override

public void onBackPressed() {

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
    startActivityForResult(intent,CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
```

}

**But cant find a way how to redirect to particular accessibility service when the button is toggled!**

[image: Screen 1]
[image: Screen 2]

Comment: Show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you will get an answer to this as that behaviour is against WCAG practices of ["predicatable behaviour"](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html#:~:text=Unexpected%20changes%20of%20context%20can,unable%20to%20use%20the%20content.&text=Individuals%20who%20are%20blind%20or,a%20new%20window%20popping%20up.). I suppose the question is why you are trying to do this (as I can't see the benefit but I may be missing something) and what you have tried / looked at so far as Eyosiyas said.

Comment: @Eyosiyas  Thanks for your reply! 

I have just updated the question where I have added the code I have tried please have a look.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie  Thanks for your reply! 

I have just updated the question where I have added the code I have tried please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

First, add SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Secondly, check if the toggle switched on.

```
switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked)
           checkPermission();
    }
}
```

Next the **checkPermission** function definition.

```
private void checkPermission() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
   if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
     startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION);
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, override **onActivityResult**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CODE_DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            //Permission granted
        }
    }
}
```